# VM downgrade suggested, Applied, Stuck

Tags: virtual-machines, wordpress, downgrade

First timer here question wise so please bear with me if I leave something out...

Google Cloud suggested I shrink one of my VM's running wordpress because of utilization, I agreed and after what seemed like forever the downgrade "failed" and my VM isn't running Wordpress, the site just times out. Can't access via FTP either.

I also can't start/stop the instance because those options are greyed out while the "wait wheel" spins even after the fail message that appears when you hover over the question mark in the top right.

Has this happened to anyone else? What do I do to get my VM back up and running?

Thanks, any questions let me know

Comment: Did you use US-East-1? GCP is currently having an outage there due to loss of power: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-networking/20005

Comment: Please check the [Google Cloud Status Dashboard](https://status.cloud.google.com/).